# How to compute the homology groups of spherical space forms?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $S^n /\Gamma$ be a spherical space form where $\Gamma<O(n+1)$ is a finite subgroup. How can we find the homology groups $H_*(S^n /\Gamma,\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: Are you familiar with spectral sequences ?

Comment: I am wondering how this is in line with the fact that orientable closed manifolds with positive curvature operator are real homology spheres. That would mean $H_p(\Gamma,\mathbb{R}) = 0$ for $p=1,\dots,n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice question with a nice answer. Since $\Gamma$ acts freely, either $n$ is even and $\Gamma$ is $\Bbb Z/2$ acting antipodally or $n$ is odd and $\Gamma \subset SO(n+1)$. I will only bother with the second case.

Because $\Gamma \subset SO(n+1)$, your action arises from the restriction to a unit sphere of $\Gamma \curvearrowright \Bbb R^{n+1}$. I will call this representation $V$. Then your sphere is the unit sphere $S(V)$, and the space you care about is $S(V)/\Gamma$.

First, give $S(V)$ a $\Gamma$-invariant cell decomposition: this arises by choosing a cell decomposition of $S(V)/\Gamma$ and taking the naturally induced cell decomposition on the universal cover. In fact, we may choose a cell decomposition of $S(V)/\Gamma$ which has one $0$-cell and one $n$-cell (by Morse theory, if you like).

Write $C_*(S(V))$ for the associated cellular chain complex; this is a chain complex of free $\Bbb Z[\Gamma]$-modules, with $H_*(S(V)) = \Bbb Z$ in degrees $0$ and $n$.

Write $$C = \bigoplus_{k \geq 0} C_*(S(V))[k(n+1)].$$ The $[j]$ means that the chain complex is shifted up by $j$ in degree. We make $C$ into a $\Bbb Z[\Gamma]$-chain complex as follows. The differential on $C_j(S(V))[k(n+1)]$ is the same as on $C_j(S(V))$ for $k = 0$ or for $j > 0$. The only difference is the map $$d: C_0(S(V))[k(n+1)] \to C_n(S(V))[(k-1)(n+1)].$$

To describe this map, first, we use what we know about the homology groups. Because $H_0(S(V)) \cong \Bbb Z$, we find that there is an isomorphism $$C_0(S(V)) \cong B_0(S(V)) \oplus \Bbb Z$$ as $\Bbb Z[\Gamma]$-modules. (The second term is the invariant chain given by taking the sum over the $\Gamma$ many $0$-cells.) Similarly, we may find a $\Gamma$-equivariant isomorphism $$C_n(S(V)) \cong \Bbb Z \oplus Z_n(S(V)).$$

For $k>0$, we define the map $$d: C_0(S(V))[k(n+1)] \to C_n(S(V))[(k-1)(n+1)]$$ to send $B_0(S(V))$ to zero and to send $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Z$. This is $\Gamma$-equivariant, so $C$ is a chain complex of free $\Bbb Z[\Gamma]$-modules. Furthermore, $C$ is a free resolution of $\Bbb Z$ (given by the augmentation $C_0(S(V)) \to \Bbb Z$, where we just sum over the weights on our $0$-cells). Therefore, the group homology $H_*(\Gamma;\Bbb Z)$ may be computed as $H_*(C \otimes_{\Bbb Z[\Gamma]} \Bbb Z)$.

What is this quotient? It is the chain complex given by assembling together shifted copies of $C_*(S(V)/\Gamma)$, with the map $C_0(S(V))/\Gamma)[k(n+1)] \to C_n(S(V)/\Gamma)[(k-1)(n+1)]$ just the identity map $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$. Therefore, its homology groups are shifted copies of the reduced homology groups of $S(V)/\Gamma$, except that we have killed off the top-degree element of homology.

In particular, for $j < n$, we find $$H_j(S(V)/\Gamma;\Bbb Z) \cong H_j(\Gamma;\Bbb Z),$$ and in fact $H_j(\Gamma;\Bbb Z)$ enjoys a periodicity: for $j > 0$, we have $$H_j(\Gamma;\Bbb Z) \cong H_{j+n+1}(\Gamma;\Bbb Z)!$$

OK, I'll admit this is a bit backwards: how do you compute group homology in this case? You probably start by writing down exactly the manifold $S(V)/\Gamma$, and compute its homology (by understanding the geometry well enough to write down a cell decomposition), and exploit the periodicity we just found! But the connection was worth stating. I doubt you will find a more satisfying answer - you will likely have to compute by hand. And at least this gives meaningful answers for eg $H_1, H_2$. And group (co)homology *can* be computed algorithmically.

Comment: Can your solution give any information about the $n$th homology group ? (In a similar vein of connecting group homology and the homology of $S(V)/\Gamma$, one can use the Cartan Leray spectral sequence, for instance for the lens space $S^3/\mathbb{Z/p}$ one gets all the information one needs, except $H_3$, for which we only get an extension $0\to \mathbb{Z}\to H_3\to \mathbb{Z/p}\to 0$, and I was wondering if there was a way to recover $H_3$ from there - and actually I'm almost certain we'll get the same for finite cyclic subgroups of $SO(n+1)$ in the odd case)

Comment: @Max Since $S(V)/\Gamma$ is an oriented manifold, the top homology is $\Bbb Z$. It's always good to hear more computational techniques.

Comment: I'll need to think about why it's oriented, but I do know about that; thanks for the tip !

Comment: @Max Oh, this is from my first paragraph (assuming you believe that claim; it's a fun little exercise). We know that $\Gamma$ must act by orientation preserving transformations, and so the orientation on $S(V)$ descends to the quotient.

Comment: Oh right, it's the $S$ that I had missed; and I do believe it, I actually know how to prove it; thanks a lot for pointing that out !

Comment: I wrote another answer to point to a use of spectral sequences; but I'm not fully familiar with them; if you have the time to check out my answer and tell me if it makes sense, I would be very grateful !

Answer (score 1):

I like Mike Miller's answer because it provides a clear and direct link with group homology. Here's another way of seeing this link, which I share because it's always interesting to have different points of view (though I'm not 100% sure of how different the two are).

The point is that when you have a free $G$-complex $X$ for a group $G$, then you have the Cartan-Leray spectral sequence whose abutment is $H_*(X/G)$, and whose second page is $E^2_{p,q} = H_p(G,H_q(X))$ where $H_q(X)$ is a $G$-module in the obvious way. In particular if you know the homology of $G$ well enough and if $H_q(X)$ is often zero (or at least often has $H_p(G,H_q(X)) = 0$) then this spectral sequence can help you compute $H_*(X/G)$.

In our example $X=S^n$; and I won't copy Mike Miller's argument to explain why $X$ can be seen as a free $\Gamma$-complex (oh and I'll also only be considering the odd $n$ case, and $\Gamma \subset SO(n+1)$), so $H_q(X)$ is often $0$ (it's always, except when $q=0,n$)

So what happens in our spectral sequence (you should definitely try to draw it a bit to see what's happening) is that it's stable up to the $r=n+1$th page (the differentials have bidegree $(-r,r-1)$), so we might as well move straight to that page, let $r=n+1$; then $E^r_{p,q} = H_p(\Gamma,H_q(S^n))$, and the only interesting differentials are $d^r : E^r_{p,0}\to E^r_{p-(n+1), n}$.

Now there are two things to notice :

1) As noted in the comments below Mike's answer, we only care about $H_k(S^n/\Gamma)$ for $k<n$ : indeed for $k=n$, $S^n/\Gamma$ is an orientable closed $n$-manifold, so its $n$th homology is $\mathbb{Z}$ (or the coefficient ring, under mild assumptions, e.g. a PID), and for $k>n$, the $k$th homology is $0$ (because it's an $n$-manifold, or an $n$-dimension CW-complex, whichever you're most comfortable with)

2) If $g\in \Gamma$ acts on $S^n$, then since $g$ has no fixed point it is homotopic to $-id : S^n\to S^n$, hence induces the same map on $0$th and $n$th homology, which is known to be $id$ in the odd case; therefore $H_p(\Gamma, H_q(S^n)) = H_p(\Gamma, \mathbb{Z})$ with the trivial action on $\mathbb{Z}$ for $q=0,n$.

With these things in mind, for $p<n$, $d^r_{p,0}: H_p(\Gamma, \mathbb{Z})\to 0$, hence $E^\infty_{p,0} = E^r_{p,0} = H_p(\Gamma, \mathbb{Z})$

Now let $F_\bullet$ be a filtration on $H_*(S^n/\Gamma)$ such that $F_pH_{p+q}(S^n/\Gamma)/F_{p-1}H_{p+q}(S^n/\Gamma) = E^\infty_{p,q}$. Notice that since $E^\infty_{p,q} = 0$ if $q\neq 0,n$ and we're only interested in $p+q<n$, it only matters what $E^\infty_{p,0}$ is, so we are done trying to figure out more terms in the $\infty$th page of the spectral sequence.

So let $k<n$, then $F_pH_k(S^n/\Gamma)/F_{p-1}H_k(S^n/\Gamma) = E^\infty_{p, k-p}$, which is $0$ as long as $p\neq k$ (because $k-p < n$), so by induction you can prove that $F_pH_k(S^n/\Gamma) = 0$ for $p<k$, and $F_kH_k(S^n/\Gamma) = F_kH_k(S^n/\Gamma)/F_{k-1}(S^n/\Gamma) = E^\infty_{k,0} = H_k(\Gamma, \mathbb{Z})$; but now it's also clear that the higher $F_l/F_{l-1}$'s are $0$.

To conclude, we need to know that the filtration we got on $H_k(S^n/\Gamma)$ is finite; but that's just a consequence of how it was built. This then tells us that $H_k(S^n/\Gamma) = F_kH_k(S^n/\Gamma) = H_k(\Gamma, \mathbb{Z}), k<n$, so we find the same result as Mike gave.

Note that my answer seems long because I took my time with the details of the computation after we got the spectral sequence, but this is mostly because I'm new to spectral sequences and I wanted to make sure everything was clear to me; I assume an expert in spectral sequence could have written this in a much more concise manner.

Oh and a last thing : Mike says that it's a bit tautological because to compute $H_k(\Gamma, \mathbb{Z})$, we'd usually try to compute the homology of $S^n/\Gamma$, but there's also a purely algebraic construction of group homology, and this can be used for some computations; the example I gave in the comments is the computation of the homology of the lens space. Indeed, the homology of a finite cyclic group is easy to compute thanks to an easy free $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$: if $P=\displaystyle\sum_{x\in G}x$ and $G=\langle g\rangle$, then there's a resolution of the form $\dots \to \mathbb{Z}[G]\to^{d_2} \mathbb{Z}[G]\to^{d_1} \mathbb{Z}[G]\to^{d_2}\mathbb{Z}[G]\to^{d_1} \mathbb{Z}[G]\to^\epsilon \mathbb{Z}$; where $d_1(1) = g-1$, $d_2(1) = P$; which makes $H_k(\mathbb{Z/nZ}, \mathbb{Z})$ really easy to compute.

Of course, as Mike pointed out, there are also algorithms to compute group homology.

Comment: I think that our answers do more or less the same things, since my chain complex is essentially built so that we understand the transgression differential. However, I think it's just as important to see the spectral sequence point of view which is invisible in my post, and I'm glad you posted this. In fact, thinking about the spectral sequence is one way you could come up with my chain complex!

Comment: How would one tackle the even n case?

Comment: @Mathy : there's only one group that can act freely on an even dimensional sphere, and it's $\mathbb Z/2$, and it's $\mathbb Z/2$ acting by the antipodal action, so that the quotient is $\mathbb RP^n$. So the only interesting case is the odd case